# How do I respect filters, when setting up Apollo server cachehints?

Tags: apollo-server, apollo-cache-inmemory

My objective is to configure my apollo node server with [server-side caching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/performance/caching/).

I struggle to understand how I would differentiate a query, depending on the filters.

With this query:

```
type GroupAverageType @cacheControl(maxAge: 1000) {
    rounded: Float!
}
# How do I respect the groupId here - so I don't cache the same thing for different groups?
expensiveGroupAverageQuery(groupId: ID!): GroupAverageType!
```

How do I cache the `expensiveGroupAverageQuery`, but **ensure** that a query for groupA won't return groupB's cached data.

Thanks in advance.